# Calculate difference between the row counts of tables in two schemas in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, difference

I have two table with same name in two different schemas (old and new dump). I would like to know the difference between the two integration.

I have two queries, that gives old and new count:

```
select count(*) as count_old from(
        SELECT 
            distinct id
        FROM 
            schema1.compound)q1
    

select count(*) as count_new from(     
        SELECT 
            distinct id
        FROM 
            schema2.compound)q2
```

I would like have the following output.

```
table_name  count_new count_new diff
compound    4740      4735      5
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: `JOIN` them together unconditionally i.e. `ON TRUE`?

Comment: @TomMac: you can even use a `cross join` as each query only returns a single row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with counts as (
    select
        (select count(distinct id) from schema1.compound) as count_old,
        (select count(distinct id) from schema2.compound) as count_new
)
select
    'compound' as table_name,
    count_old,
    count_new,
    count_old - count_new as   diff
from counts;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do something like this:

```
SELECT 'compound' AS table_name, count_old, count_new, (count_old - count_new) AS diff FROM ( 
    SELECT( 
        (SELECT count(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM schema1.compound)) AS count_old,
        (SELECT count(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM schema2.compound)) AS count_new
    )
```

It was probably answered already, but it is a subquery/nested query.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly compute the `COUNT` on distinct values if you use the `DISTINCT` keyword inside your aggregation function. Then you can join the queries extracting your two needed values, and use them inside your query to get the output table.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT new.cnt AS count_new,
           old.cnt AS count_old
    FROM       (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) AS cnt FROM schema1.compound) AS old
    INNER JOIN (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) AS cnt FROM schema2.compound) AS new
            ON 1 = 1
)
SELECT 'compound' AS table_name,
       count_new,
       count_old,
       count_new = count_old AS diff
FROM cte
```

Comment: There is no point in using JOIN - just list them both.